# Most Recent R Version (Windows): Function Error in Reading Files: Reading A List of Files & Calculating Correlation

Tags: r, function, file, vector, connection

This is my first post on Stack Overflow, so please bear with me.  I will try to be as  proper as I know thus far!

I am taking the Coursera Data Science course from Johns Hopkins University, so I hope this might provide some context as to what I am trying to achieve.  [Specifically, my question involves Course 2: Week 2: Programming Assignment 1: Part 3]

I am using the **most recent** version of R.

**Question I Am Trying To Answer**
Write a function that takes a directory of data files and a threshold for complete cases and calculates the `correlation` between `sulfate` and `nitrate` for monitor locations where the number of completely observed cases (on all variables) is greater than the threshold. The function should return a vector of correlations for the monitors that meet the threshold requirement. If no monitors meet the threshold requirement, then the function should return a numeric vector of length 0.

**Short Version** So basically, the function I have to create will read an entire list of .csv files, and if the number of complete cases/rows of data in each file is greater than a specified number, the correlation between two variables in each of those files will be added to a numeric vector.

**My Steps** The steps I tried to execute to achieve this are:

(1) Create an empty vector to hold the correlation data

(2) List the files in the directory I need to read from

(3) Read every file, and IF the number of complete cases in that file is greater than a threshold passed to the function, add the correlation between two variables ("`sulfate`", "`nitrate`") to the original numeric vector.

Here is the code I have written to try and achieve this:

```
pollutantCorrelations <- function(threshold = 0) {

    # Create an empty numeric vector to hold the data from this operation
    correlations <- numeric()

    # List the files that can be called on
    fileList <- list.files(path = "C:/Users/amcco/Documents/Coursera/Data Science/Course 2. R Programming/Programming Assignment 1/specdata", pattern = ".csv")

    for(i in fileList) {
            data <- read.csv(fileList[i]) # Read each file in the list of files

            # If the number of complete cases in 'data' is greater than the threshold, calculate it and append the correlation to the original vector 
            if(sum(complete.cases(data)) > threshold) {
                    correlations <- c(correlations, cor(data[,"sulfate"], data[,"nitrate"], use = "complete.obs"))
            } # Do not have to include an else statement

            correlations
    }
}
```

I expected this function to return a numeric vector with each numeric element representing the correlation of a set of variables for each read file.

For example, `[-0.6353, 0.4242, 0.35225, 0.356643, ...]`

However, I am receiving the following notification:

> ```
>  *Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection In addition: Warning message: In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file
> ```
>
> 'NA': No such
>        file or directory*

This is annoying, since this exact same directory and method has worked for previous functions.  I do not believe there is an issue with the directory, but I would be very grateful if anyone could help me identify what is going wrong here!

Thank you :)

Comment: Make sure that `fileList` paths are accessible from your workspace. You can use `full.names` argument to construct full paths, not just file names.

Comment: That did not change anything.  Please help :(